# Why are my variables empty when I cast them in my iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

**Hi,**
I am coding an application on Xcode for IOS and I would like to send a variable to another ViewController. The problem is that when I want to send from the controller called **"Step1"** to set the label of my second view controller called **"Step2"**. To do this I proceed in this way in **"Step 1"**:

```
guard let step2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Step2) as? EndConfiguration else
        {
            fatalError("Error when trying to get the reference to the Step 2")
        }

step2.nameLabelOutlet?.text = "Jonh"
```

But my label is not set... Could someone help me with this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should probably be `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EndConfiguration")`

Comment: Ups sorry I modified my code to try to make things easier for you to understand.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: iBOutlets are not set until the view is loaded. The view isn't loaded until the view controller is presented or until `view` is referenced or you call `loadViewIfNeeded`. However, it is poor form to refer directly to a UI element from outside the owning view controller.  I would suggest that you assign the text to a new string property in your destination view controller and the assign that string to your label in somewhere like `viewDidLoad' or `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @Paulw11 good catch on the code trying to access IBOutlet from the newly instantiated view controller. I missed that part.

Comment: @aheze The problem is accessing another ViewController to modify a variable.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks you for you answer. Oh yes it's true that the ViewController and thus the iBOutlet are not yet created. So I tried to do this in my Step 1:  ibb.co/xDNCXYQ and this in the Step 2: ibb.co/x7RZSm9 but my var is empty... Have I done something wrong?

Comment: You don't actually present `step2`, so it will just be thrown away at the end of the function. Have you also connected the second view controller via a storyboard segue?  You must either Crete the new view controller and present it programmatically or use a storyboard

Comment: Yes I have a storyboard with my two view controllers which are children of a navigation controller. https://ibb.co/jHsQjnx

Answer (score 1):

### EDITED:

There are 3 parts to debugging the problem:

1. Does the call to `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` return a viewController? As @aheze points out, you're passing an identifier of `EndConfiguration`. Unless that is a string constant (e.g. `let EndConfiguration = "EndConfiguration"`) that seems odd. Since you're trying to cast the returned object to type `EndConfiguration` it seems clear that something isn't right. (`EndConfiguration` can't  be both a view controller class and a string constant.) 
   To debug the call to `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` you should get rid of the cast (the `as? EndConfiguration` bit) and see if the call returns a view controller.
2. The second part is the conditional cast (The `as? EndConfiguration` bit.) If what is created is not a view controller of class `EndConfiguration` that will fail. It's pretty easy to accidentally leave your view controller's class as the default class `UIViewController`, and not change it to your custom class in Interface builder. To check that open your storyboard, select the scene for that view controller, select the view controller in that scene, and check in the "identity inspector" that the class is your `EndConfiguration` class.
3. As pointed out by PaulW in his comment, a view controller's views are not loaded by the time it's returned in a call to `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`, so your code `step2.nameLabelOutlet?.text = "Jonh"` won't work because nameLabelOutlet will be nil. Plus, you shouldn't manipulate another view controller's views. Treat them as private. You should add a string property to the target view controller that IT picks up in viewWillAppear and installs in it's view as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks you so muck for your answer, 
1) I do this : https://ibb.co/6PbhkZ9 so  print my variable named "Step2", it returns: "<Alarm.Step2: 0x7fbdd6b13df0>". In my storyboard I have a view controller with an identifier "Step1" and a cocoa touch class named in the same way. 
2) That sounds good to me: https://ibb.co/PQyH6pM
3) It actually makes sense, so I did that in Step1 : https://ibb.co/xDNCXYQ and that in step 2 : https://ibb.co/x7RZSm9
Thanks again for the help

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then you should accept it. (It is quite hard to follow your series of screen-shots of tiny snippets of code.)

Comment: No unfortunately this is not solved. I have recreated an empty project with just my mistake, if you have time I will be grateful. https://mega.nz/folder/ZnxQ1DwK#3VQ8dTuQk58EOP-ztE9NYg