# pass qr image to another view controller

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, viewcontroller

Im a newbie in swift. I'm trying to pass my image to UIImageView on another view controller but error message "Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage' to type 'UIImageView' came out. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[First view controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb6hw.png)

[Second view controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLa97.png)

Comment: Embed your code as text instead of an image

Comment: But anyway you should do `SecondController.QRImage.image = image`, not `SecondController.QRImage = image`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! its fixed :D

Comment: Np, but you should name all variables with the first letter lowercased, like `let secondController` and `@IBOutlet weak var refreshButton`

Comment: May I ask why it must be lowercased?

Comment: It's just a convention in Swift that everyone follows. If you do things differently, other people will have a harder time understanding your code. Here's a [guide](https://riptutorial.com/swift/example/10304/capitalization) -- you'll get used to it quickly

Comment: hey sorry but I've encountered a "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" at the same part. how can I fix it>

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65256352/14351818). Is `QRImage` nil, or `image` nil?

Comment: the nil is QRImage, ive tried added loadViewIfNeeded() but another error occurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are you doing:

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage() // <- its create image
let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView() // its create some kind of container

imageView = image // ERROR!
```

you trying to set object with type UIImage to object with type UIImageView

correct:

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage() 
let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView() 

imageView.image = image
```